# Fabric App for Mac crash in background

Tags: google-fabric

This suddenly appears these days. I use Xcode 9.2.
Every time I use `command+R` to run my APP the explorer will be launched and open fabric website. At this time the Fabric App could not be open. It was crash in the background even it was not opened. I must close Xcode. I tried open Fabric App first then open Xcode. After few hours this happens again, every time use `command+R` would open fabric website. At that time the Fabric App was freeze. The only way to close it was force quit.
Does anyone have the same problem?

More information. It's often happens after long time using Xcode, maybe more than 5 hours. It maybe have some issue with Interface Builder. I use @IBDesinable classes in storyboard and there are more than 10 xibs in this storyboard. It has more probability that Xcode build this storyboard after long time working occurs Fabric App crash.

I use Xcode 9.2 and macOS 10.12.6

Comment: Mike from Firebase here. I haven't heard of other reports of this issue. With the Fabric app closed, try running this command to clear the local cache: rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.mac

Comment: @MikeBonnell I add some more informations. It maybe has something with storyboard. I used IBDesinable classes, so the storyboard will compile more often. After long time working it happens often.

Comment: Thanks, did the other suggestion help at all?

Comment: @MikeBonnell No, clear cache do not help.

Comment: In that case, best to contact support(at)fabric(dot)io so they can look into this more.